# How to debug Spring web application without real web request in IntelliJ

Tags: java, spring, servlets

I want to debug a Spring controller class with IntelliJ. Normally I would start the service in debug mode and perform a real REST request to enter the breakpoint.

But is it possible to invoke spring bean without an active servlet request and execution thread? Ideally, I would like to attach java REPL to an existing process and call arbitrary spring beans without web request.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to write integration/unit tests using Mock MVC and then execute a selected test case in debug mode in IDEA. Mock MVC is easy to use , you can get some basic idea from this link  https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot2/testing/spring-boot-mockmvc-example/

Comment: This answer concerns "testing" while the question is about "debugging"

Comment: @irkwz , this question precisely ask how do we debug RestController (in IDEA )without an active servlet request. this explain the best and probably only the way it can be done, write a MOCK mvc and then debug it.